# Prepared statement mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting obsessed. I'm working for the first time with prepared statement and I am sure I have read somewhere that you could prepare a statement like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO {$table} (:var1, :var2) VALUES (:val1, :val2)");
$stmt->bind_param(':var1', $var1);
$stmt->bind_param(':var2', $var2);
$stmt->bind_param(':val1', $val1);
$stmt->bind_param(':val2', $val2);
$stmt->execute();
```

Or something like that. I remember that I have read that you could call the vars with a specific name with ':' as prefix. But I really can't find an example of that. I read the php manual and I couldn't find any sample of this thing.
Is it right or have I dreamed it?

**Faq**

If you are wondering why I can't use simply the '?' method:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO {$table} (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

this gets hard to write.

Comment: Pigarelli - Are you refering to `select @current_time:=NOW(); select @current_time;` ? PS: Not too sure binding on column is allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `:var1`,`:var2`,`:varX` in both the column names list and the `VALUES` list for one thing. Secondly, PDO accepts named parameter binding.

See [PHP Data Objects](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and examples in [PDO::prepare](http://de.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).